# Why doesn't this curiously recurring template pattern example compile?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, crtp

I believe this is an example of the curiously recurring template pattern.  It seems to me that this should compile, but it does not.  This is with Clang in Xcode 8.3.

```
template<class T>
class Fungeable
{
public:
    virtual ~Fungeable() {}
    virtual bool funge( const Fungeable<T>& inFungeable ) const = 0;
};

class Blarg : public Fungeable<Blarg>
{
public:
    virtual bool funge( const Blarg& inFungeable ) const override { return true; }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Blarg b;
    Blarg x;
    return static_cast<int>( b.funge( x ) );
}
```

It seems like this should work because Blarg *is a* Fungeable.  But I get the error `'funge' marked 'override' but does not override any member functions`

If I change the signature of `Blarg::funge()` to take a `Fungeable<Blarg>` like this:

```
class Blarg : public Fungeable<Blarg>
{
public:
    virtual bool funge( const Fungeable<Blarg>& inFungeable ) const override { return true; }
};
```

Then it compiles.

Shouldn't the first version work since `Blarg` is, by definition, a `Fungeable<Blarg>`?

Comment: "since Blarg is, by definition, a Fungeable<Blarg>" Every `Blarg` is a `Fungeable<Blarg>` but not every `Fungeable<Blarg>` is a `Blarg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Co-variant parameter types don't, never have, and most probably never will work in C++. You may think your example is "obviously" safe. But the feature is un-safe in general, and adding support for such a small use case won't happen.

To illustrate:

```
struct food {};
struct grass : food {};

struct animal {
  virtual void eat(food&) = 0;
};

void feed(animal& a) {
  a.eat(grass{});
}
```

So far so good. Now, let's add more to the hierarchy, assuming we have co-variant parameter types:

```
struct meat : food {};

struct lion : animal {
  void eat(meat&) {/*...*}
};
```

What happens when I pass a `lion` object to `feed`? It can't handle `grass` as food, but it **is-a** `animal`. This breaks the Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: In your first sentence do you mean 'parameter' instead of 'return'?

Comment: @MatthewJamesBriggs - Whoops. Yes I do. Co-variant return type are supported, so major mistake on my part.